# I'm not understanding the optional group syntax in regex

Tags: php, regex, time, duration

This is my test string/phrase/text ...

> 8:58 pm uberX 32m 0s 13.87

The duration time can be day, hours, minutes and seconds.  I'm probably never ever going to see days but hours is possible.

```
(\d+)m.(\d+)s
```

Which in this case give me 32 and 0 in a php preg_match statement.

Now I tried putting (\d+)h?. in front of the above regex and putting a 2h in my test string and I broke it.

Trying to learn regex bit by bit by bit.

I'm grateful for whatever help comes my way!
Thank you!

Comment: See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k70HfN/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/(\d+(?=d\W))|(\d+(?=h\W))|(\d+(?=m\W))|(\d+(?=s\W))/
```

This uses positive lookahead to only match digits immediately followed by d, h, m or s

Answer (score 1):

The ? applies to the token immediately preceding it. In your example, it makes the h optional, but the digits are still mandatory. You can make this work by enclosing the whole part you with to make optional in a non capturing group: `(?:(\d+)h)?`